# I have a C program that takes the day of the year but I'm having trouble

Tags: c

I have a C program that I am suppose to input the day of the year and it returns month and the day in the month but when I run it, it gives all of the months leading up to that month and I just want to to output one month. I am not sure why here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day);

int main() {
  int month[13] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
  int year, dayofyear, *day;

  printf("Enter the day of the year: ");
  scanf("%d", &dayofyear);
  printf("Enter the year: ");
  scanf("%d", &year);
  printf("Day %d of year %d falls on:\n ",dayofyear, year);

  SplitDate(dayofyear, year, month, day);
}

void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day)
{
  if(dayofyear >=1 || dayofyear <= 31)
  {
    printf("month = 1    day = %d\n",dayofyear);
  }

  if(dayofyear >=32 || dayofyear <= 60)
  {
    printf("month = 2   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 31);
  }

  if(dayofyear >=61 || dayofyear <=92)
  {
    printf("month = 3  day = %d\n", dayofyear - 59);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` conditions in the function `SplitDate` should be using `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: I knew it was simple but I thought that I would have to use or... thank you, @AntonH

Comment: Try saying your conditions out loud, I find it sometimes helps makes the choice between 'and' and 'or' clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as noted, `||` must be changed to `&&`, for you want an AND condition, not an OR one.

After that, you must return from `SplitDate()` after the comparison.  One way to accomplish this is by using `return`.

```
void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day)
{
  if(dayofyear >=1 && dayofyear <= 31)
    {
      printf("month = 1    day = %d\n",dayofyear);
      return;
    }
  if(dayofyear >=32 && dayofyear <= 60)
    {
      printf("month = 2   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 31);
      return;
    }
  if(dayofyear >=61 && dayofyear <=92)
    {
      printf("month = 3  day = %d\n", dayofyear - 59);
      return;
    }
}
```

Another, perhaps better way is to use an `if-else` construct.

```
void SplitDate(int dayofyear, int year, int *month, int *day)
{
  if(dayofyear >=1 && dayofyear <= 31)
    {
      printf("month = 1    day = %d\n",dayofyear);
    }
  else if(dayofyear >=32 && dayofyear <= 60)
    {
      printf("month = 2   day = %d\n", dayofyear - 31);
    }
  else if(dayofyear >=61 && dayofyear <=92)
    {
      printf("month = 3  day = %d\n", dayofyear - 59);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  If it has been an useful answer, would you please mark it as such?  :)

Comment: how do I do that @RobertoReale ?

Comment: By clicking on the "tick" sign just beneath the big gray ZERO near the top of my answer...

Comment: Thank you!  This will help others to quickly spot the answer, as well as improving my reputation. :)

Comment: No problem and, would there be a way the I could simplify this program or no @RobertoReale

Comment: You could use a `for` loop, plus the data you already have in the `month` array.

Comment: hmm ok, I'm new to this but I'll see how far I can get thank you @RobertoReale

Comment: In case, we are here to help.